# Force a method specified in an interface to only be defined outside of an abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

Here's one I've been scratching my head over for a while now.

Suppose you want to specify a method in an interface, but you don't want it actually defined until the implementation level. That is to say, you want to specify a method in an interface such that if it is defined in an abstract class the compiler will throw an error.

```
public interface Thing{   

    public void method1();

    public void method2();

    //method3 should be implementation specific
    public void method3();

}
```

And then I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class BasicThing{

    @Override
    public void method1(){}

    @Override
    public void method2(){}

}
```

And my implementation specific code:

```
public class ThingImpl{

    @Override
    public void method3(){}

}
```

(By the way, I know that it's an valid to just write it this way, but my reason in wanting to do this is so that if I'm writing the interface and passing it along to someone else who then passes it along to do the final implementation, I want to be able to force the extra specification on them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way of doing this at compile-time. It's a pretty odd requirement too, IMO.

You can do it the co-operation of the abstract class of course, as Sheik's answer shows. But you can't *force* an abstract class to do that by virtue of putting something specific in the interface.

You could potentially try to find all the relevant classes and validate your requirements in a unit test.

Comment: Maybe it's a little odd, but no one ever faulted a developer for being too explicit :D

Too bad though, I wish there was a more elegant solution . . .

Answer (score 1):

You should use an abstract method in your abstract BasicThing class.

```
public abstract void method3();
```

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the question, but I believe the OP wants to enforce this on the *interface*, not in the abstract class.

Comment: I have reread the question and I think your right (as per usual :P) seems like a very strange thing to want to do.  OP can you provide any details on why you want to do this, I'm intrigued.

Comment: Thanks Sheik, I was mulling that over but Jon has it right--I want to write the interface only, and then pass it along for someone else to write some generic code in an abstract class. The thing is, I want them to implement as much as they see fit, but so as they don't get too excited and run away with it, I want to force it so that certain methods cannot be defined in an abstract class, and must be defined by the (different) person writing the implementation specific class.

Comment: @user1551209 sounds like you rather have a process issue than a SW one.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think what u need is an anonymous inner-class implementations for your interface.

public class MyClass{

public void do something()
{
    Thing th1=new Thing(){

     @Override
     public void method3(){
     System.out.println("****My Method3***");
     }
    };

    th1.method3();
}
};
```